# Is there any way to use https.createServer on chrome app?

Tags: node.js, sockets, google-chrome-extension, https, google-chrome-app

I am using [this chromify approach](https://github.com/iceddev/node-chromify) to develop a chrome app in NodeJS. I need to mount a simple HTTPS server, but node-chromify doesn't support that feature, only HTTP. So, my question: Is there any way to mount a single HTTPS server from a chrome app/extension? With ot without node.js

Comment: I Found [this](https://github.com/whiteout-io/tcp-socket), seems to be the answer for this problem

Answer (score 0):

It should technically be possible since at least Chrome 38, which has a [`chrome.socket.secure()`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket#method-secure) method that upgrades an existing TCP socket to a TLS socket.

However seeing as the `chromify` project hasn't been updated since 2012, you may have to do a little work to incorporate this recent API.